# Load image from Disk Windows Phone 8.1 on a List view?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I working with a listView that has a image on every item, that image is fetched from disk but that image not necessary does not exits.

The issue happens when the image does not exits, its takes too long to throw a `FileNotFoundException` (on console) and it freeze the `UI`.

My list view is something like this

```
<ListView 
    Name="TestLv" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Imageview Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And I got a converter to build the url imageSource on disk

```
class Image : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var itemService = value as ClassItem;

        if(someCondition){
            return .. //compose file system url
        }

        //return an static image
        return ..
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Or if there's a better way to do this, perfect I'm all ears.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)". BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: OK. Thank for those advice.

Answer (score 0):

There other better ways to implement this but for not freezing UI you can implement asycn something like this.

```
    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Image> LoadImageAsync(string imagename)
    { 

        //Get Image from local storage...
        return yourimage
    }
```

and your converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    var itemService = value as ClassItem;

    if(someCondition){
        return LoadImageAsync(imagename);
    }

    //return an static image
    return ..
}
```

Comment: I can not do that, if i do that I need to change the Converter to an async method witch means that the interface IValueConverter will not be implemented.